# Percentage of Questions Upvoted Lower than the Highest Upvoted Answer

Tags: support, app-request, script-request

On another site the issue has come up that questions may not be upvoted but answers are.  I would like to get some statistical support for this.  Are there already existing apps that can do this kind of analysis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not something you could obtain from the API. The API basically exposes some of the features of the site (e.g. search, writing posts, voting itself) in a programmatic way. For analysis like this, you'll need SEDE, the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) and support for that is on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-explorer); there's even a [chatroom](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede) dedicated to SEDE.

That said, the answer to your question is about 55% on Music Stack Exchange, as this [relatively simple SEDE query shows](https://data.stackexchange.com/music/query/1158913/percentage-of-questions-upvoted-lower-than-the-highest-upvoted-answer). If you're interested, you should definitely read the [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial).